# Как функцию написать в условие if?

Tags: javascript

Я новичок, есть вопрос по поводу функции.
Есть определенная функция, которая возвращает результат. Мне нужно, чтобы результат этой функции можно было ввести в качестве условия в if, и дальше выполнялся if.
Как правильно мне это сделать?

Разные варианты, например: if (function3 !== null) { } ; if (function3 !== undefind) { } ; if (function3 !== null) { } Я не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы результат функции был условием для выполнения if

Comment: лучше прикрепить кусок кода

Comment: В смысле, что я пробовал сделать? Разные варианты, например: if (function3 !== null) {
} ;  if (function3 !== undefind) {
} ;  if (function3 !== null) {
}
Я не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы результат функции был условием для выполнения if

Comment: ``function3()`` - про скобки не забываем!

Answer (score 1):

```
function isAdmin() {
    return true;
}

if (isAdmin()) {
    console.log('Можно всех удалить! Круто!');
} else {
    console.log('Я не всемогущ :-(');
}
```

---

или

```
function getNumber() {
    return 10;
}

let myNumber = 5;
if (myNumber > getNumber()) {
    console.log('Ага! Я победил!');
} else {
    console.log('Как всегда не везёт :-(');
}
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

В любой из вариантов (два из которых одинаковые) нужно добавить скобки, потому что вызов функции осуществляется со скобками:

```
if (function3() !== null) { } ;

if (function3() !== undefind) { } ;
```